# Set variable for all controllers and views to use

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'd like to set a public variable that's in my `BaseController` from all pages/views, if possible.  I have a partial view called `header.cshtml` that has a dropdown list full of customers and their id's.  When the user selects a customer, I need to store that `CustomerId` value into the public variable on the `BaseController`.  If my approach is wrong, please correct me but I need a way for a user to select a customer, then navigate to another page (that has the header view in it) and the dropdown needs to retain the customer they selected on the previous page.

Here's my `BaseController`:

```
public class BaseController : Controller
{
    private CurrentUser _currentUser;
    public CurrentUser CurrentUser { get; set; }

    protected override void Initialize(RequestContext requestContext)
    {
        base.Initialize(requestContext);

        Session.TryGetAuthenticatedValue(out _currentUser);
        CurrentUser = _currentUser;
    }

    public ActionResult SetSelectedCustomerId(int value)
    {
        CurrentUser.SelectedCustomerId = value;
        return Json(new { success = true });
    }
}
```

`Header.cshtml`:

```
<div class="col-md-3" style="padding-top:5px;">
    @Html.DropDownList("customers", ViewBag.CustomerList as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>,
        "--Select Customer--",
        new
        {
            @id = "ddlCustomer",
            @style = "width:390px;",
            @onchange = "javascript:SetCustomerId(this.value);",
            @class = "form-control"
        });
</div>
```

The part I'm missing is the ajax or other method in which to call the public action on the BaseController.

Comment: If you need the customerid on every page and only for the current session you could cache it in the browser localstorage and retrieve it as needed.

Comment: Right, but the CustomerId is a property off the CurrentUser object, which holds more Id's for other important info as well.  I wanted to avoid stuffing everything into a session variable and possibly exposing all the unnecessary data.  If I have the Id's, I can perform `Gets` and retrieve only the information needed.

Comment: Well, you only mentioned selected customerId :) In general I'm not a fan of base controllers to use them as "storage" as that quickly gets out of control and then you end up with bulky basecontrollers being spun up with every single controller instance. If you need persisted selection states I would possibly look into caching somewhere, front-end, back-end application cache etc... Also,..if you don't want to cache the CurrentUser object as it contains irrelevant data to some areas,..that might be a sign to refactor data you need application wide cached from the more specific data?

Comment: Good points....I'm fairly new to the MVC world as I spend 90% of my development time in WinForms.  In our old website, which uses WebForms, we used a Singleton class and stored everything in session....which was a bad idea because, as you said, it gets out of control quickly.

Comment: You should use TempData to store CurrentUser. In every action called by the "wizard" pages, you retrieve it, update it, and put it back at the end. TempData stores information between calls. You can also store it in the session for a longer storage (not permanent). If you need this between sessions, I'd consider saving to a database.

Comment: We definitely do not need it across Sessions.....if I use TempData, then I have to store/retrieve it from every action on every controller (well, maybe 90% of the actions).  This is what I would like to avoid, if possible.